# Django sample DeleteView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Example of Django Class-Based DeleteView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531258/example-of-django-class-based-deleteview)

after hours search i just didn't know how to use DeleteView. Sorry for my foolish?
Can some one give me a example?

```
url( r'^del/$', DeleteFormView.as_view( ) ),

class DeleteFormView( BaseDeleteView ):
    model = user_info
    context_object_name = "user_info_list"
```

**DeleteFormView must be called with either an object pk or a slug**
  this error always exist
  What am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

As the error says, you need to pass some sort of parameter to the view so it knows which item to delete... for example:

```
url(r'^del/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', DeleteFormView.as_view()),
```

Comment: Sorry, but i still could not understand how DeleteView works......

Answer (score 0):

[Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531258/example-of-django-class-based-deleteview) might answer some of your questions. You are on the right track, and like @Daniel said, there needs to be some sort of identifier in the URL to pass to the view to tell it what to delete.

For a full example with a template, [look to the Django-users form](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-users/zNdNE3BoGT4)