# Using Django's CBV, how can I check if request.user == my_model.user?

Tags: django

When I was using function-based views, I used to do this a lot:

```
def my_view(request, username):
  user = get_object_or_404(User, username = username)
  if user != request.user:
    return HttpRequestForbidden()
```

This coded made sure that only user `john` could access pages like `/users/john/edit/`.

How can I do the same using class-based views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question seems to be a duplicate of [Example of Django Class-Based DeleteView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531258/example-of-django-class-based-deleteview)

This is how to do it:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    """ Hook to ensure object is owned by request.user. """
    obj = super(MyDeleteView, self).get_object()
    if not obj.owner == self.request.user:
        raise Http404
    return obj
```