# Django - avoid current users from deleting themselfs

Tags: django, python-3.x

Admin (current user) who are logged in can delete himself and I want to avoid that, since it throws the error **AnonymousUser**.

There are no issues related to this that I can see since most of them are asking for is in **Django Admin Site** which is not what I want.

Still a newbie so appreciate all the help, folks!

---

models.py

```
class Administrator(AbstractUser):
   union_position = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   association = models.ForeignKey(Association)


   class Meta:
       db_table = 'Administrator'
```

---

views.py

```
class admin_delete(DeleteView):
   model = Administrator
   success_url = reverse_lazy('admin_overview')
   template_name = 'admin/admin_delete.html'
```

---

Comment: There are answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531258/example-of-django-class-based-deleteview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example of Django Class-Based DeleteView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531258/example-of-django-class-based-deleteview)