# Django: How to prevent another user from updating or deleting a post to a profile that does not correspond?

Tags: python, django

How can I prevent a user from modifying a post that does not correspond to him?
Example: a user enters to: www.localhost: 8080 / profile / number / emergency / update / 1 <- avoid that the auto-incremental post that the database has (the model) I can not modify to one that does not correspond to he.

Example of a view I have

**view.py**

```
def EmergenciaUpdate(request, emergencia_id):
     instancia = get_object_or_404(Emergencia,id=emergencia_id)
     form = EmergenciaUpdateForm(request.POST or None, instance=instancia)
     if request.method == 'POST':
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
             return redirect('emergencialista')
     return render(request, 'app/emergenciaupdate.html', {'emergencia_update_form':form})
```

**url.py**

```
url(r'^perfil/numero/emergencia/update/(?P<emergencia_id>\d+)/$', EmergenciaUpdate, name='emergenciaupdate'),
```

Comment: What you are asking for is authorization.  You should store the user who created the post in the db.  Ensure the user that is sending the request is the same user.  To do this, you will need authentication, to ensure the user is who they say they are.  Django has an authentication and authorization system built in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/

Comment: This question is related and has some possible solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531258/example-of-django-class-based-deleteview . Not necessarily a duplicate though, as you're not using class-based views at the moment.

Comment: I use function for that. Class-based has no problem.